# Cannot post a particuliar data with jQuery Form Plugin ajaxForm

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, plupload, jquery-forms-plugin

I 'm trying to use these 2 jQuery plugins : [plupload](http://www.plupload.com) and [jQuery Form Plugin ajaxForm](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

It works fine except one thing : I can't send the file.name (with ajaxForm) of the file previously uploded with plupload.

I explain a little bit:  the user sends a file with plupload. The file is uploded. It works fine.

Then, the user submits a form with ajaxForm and send form datas + the file name with post method.

I know how to send data with ajaxform, this code works fine :

```
var value1 = "dynamic_value1";
$('#my_form').ajaxForm({ 
        // datas is sent in post method, it works fine
        data: { value1: value1 }, 
        beforeSubmit: validate,
            success: function() { 
            // it's ok :
            //alert(value1);
        } 
    });
```

But i can't do this with pluplopad file.name, i can see the file name if i made an alert but i can't send it :

Plupload code to get the file name (it works) :
var file_name_vous;

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {

            // It's ok : i can get file name, alert show me the file name
            file_name_vous = encodeURIComponent(file.name);
            alert(file_name_vous);
        //};
    });
});
```

But i can't do this, this code doesn't work :

```
$participer_form.ajaxForm({ 
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
        // impossible to send this var
        file_name_vous: file_name_vous
        }, 
        beforeSubmit: validate,

            // success 
            success: function() { 
                // It's ok, alert shows the file name 
                alert(file_name_vous);    
        } 
    });
```

So what i don't understand, i can send datas with post method, i've tested it. But I can't send this particular var : file_name_vous = encodeURIComponent(file.name);

do you know if there is something i should do with (file.name) before trying to send it by post method ?

I have no error, simply in firebug networks / XHR, i don't see anything about this var. If i replace this var by var value1 = "dynamic_value1", it works. so i guess, my issue is about this partuliar var file.name

Comment: Why are you using plupload???

Malsups Ajax Form plugin support uploading via AJAX infact it supports it in the best way possible it build the data that the browser builds when it's submitting a form with File upload in them you don't need another, if you want progress of your uploads im sure the AJAX Form plugin has support for this

Comment: as to my last comment, about file upload via ajax form see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883564/get-form-id-using-jquery-plugin-ajaxform-and-upload-progress-bar

Comment: What I guess is that `file_name_vous` is populating with values after submission.

Comment: @Ravi I'm not sure file_name_vous is populating with values after submission because alert(file_name_vous); is ok when i create it and is ok too after the form is submited "success: function()"

Comment: @MartinBarker Thanks for the advice. I'll try Malsups Ajax Form upload options. I was using plupload because i've tried several plugin and this one was easy to use and it is provided with all the php files.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/PHzxy/ here is an example using the progress bar, using malsups it works with the native php form submission $_GET, here is an example using a standard form build that working then add AJAX form to it then you will get the best understanding of what your php is doing and how it is done,http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: I had same problem with ajaxForm. It creates data: { value1: value1 } on load, so you can't change it. I gave up into having something like this $('#my_form').ajaxForm({ url : 'site.com/?value1=value1'});

Comment: @dikirill Thanx, i also think the issue is related to ajaxForm. I've triple checked and the data i try to send exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you you should leave out the data part of your ajax form, and simply create an hidden field upon successful upload which will be submitted with your form.

Something like this :

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {

            // It's ok : i can get file name, alert show me the file name
            file_name_vous = encodeURIComponent(file.name);
            // maybe you'll have to check if hidden filed already exists
            $participer_form.Append($('<input type="hidden" value="'+file_name_vous+'" id="file_name_vous" name="file_name_vous"/>'));
        //};
```

Hope this will help

BTW, have you tried this, to set the value as late as possible ?

```
uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function(up, file, response) {

            // It's ok : i can get file name, alert show me the file name
            file_name_vous = encodeURIComponent(file.name);
    $participer_form.ajaxForm({ 
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
            // impossible to send this var
            file_name_vous: file_name_vous
            }, 
            beforeSubmit: validate,

                // success 
                success: function() { 
                    // It's ok, alert shows the file name 
                    alert(file_name_vous);    
            } 
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, It's exactly what i've done : file_name = encodeURIComponent(file.name); $('input#file_name').val(file_name); It shows that the issue is related to ajaxForm because in this case there is no problem with file.name

Comment: @SébastienGicquel maybe you can try setting the value later in the process. Added another option to my answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ! I've spent a couple of hours on this and finally it was a logical issue